# django redirect throw 302 and not redirecting

Tags: python, django, django-views

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
...
if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get("go_to_review"):
            app = Appointment.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("go_to_review"), status="COMPLETED")
            has_review = Feedback.objects.filter(appointment=app)
            print(f"has view : {bool(has_review)}")
            if bool(has_review):
                return redirect("patient:patient_profile")
```

my **urls.py**

```
...
path("", patient_dashboard_view, name="patient_dashboard_view"),
path("profile/", PatientProfileSetting.as_view(), name="patient_profile"),
...
```

server log is as :

```
...
HTTP GET /static/img/favicon.png 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:58430]
has view : True
HTTP POST /patient/ 302 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:58458]
value of user inside the get_data
HTTP GET /patient/profile/ 200 [0.19, 127.0.0.1:58458]
...
```

actually it renders the other view(when i put a print statement on other view it prints that, but redirecting mean it doesn't render that view in screen but it switches to that. As I'm new to django correct me if explained wrong).

~thanks in advance

Comment: The print will always be shown, as this is on the server side and not on the client side. A redirect is basically a header that is being send to the client and then doing the new call. So it is important that you don't send any content to the user before redirecting.

Comment: A status code 302 **is** a redirect.

Comment: @David thanks for reply Sir,  i will take of that :) , but how it helps me here?

Comment: @Klaus Thanks for reply sir, I've no idea why then why not redirecting to the page

Comment: @AliAref you say it renders that view (meaning the url changes and that page i.e.  /patient/profile/ shows up) that **is** redirecting.

Comment: yep but the content doesn't change from the client side :/